# Do we need to check if a Stream in java 8 if it is null and not iterate

Tags: java, java-8

Is it recommended/good approach to check if a stream is not empty or not null before iterating

What I can think of is assiging stream() to Stream vairable and check empty and null

Is there any java 8 function/feature to check that?

ref :- https://www.baeldung.com/java-null-safe-streams-from-collections

Comment: Closely related [Null safe Collection as Stream in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590134/null-safe-collection-as-stream-in-java-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not necessary¹.

As long as you use empty Streams instead of null (for example as method parameters), everything works just fine. You don't need to check if a `Stream` is empty, just like you don't need to check if a `Collection` is empty, if you use empty collections instead of nulls in your code (and you should).

¹ Now this is assuming "original" streams coming from a continuous source (collection, generator). You can easily create a null-containing Stream with something like `map(o -> o.getPossiblyNull())`. In this case you may want to use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to remove any null elements from the Stream.

Comment: Second part? Checking null in java 8 funtion? Will it work. Instead of cars.stream().map() using Optional.ofNullable(cars).map()

Comment: @PSatishPatro that's abusing `Optional` and has nothing to do with streams.

Comment: Well, I want to proceed streaming only if it is not null or else streaming over a null collection will give NullPointerException. So, I was thinking about how to handle that in java 8.

Comment: @PSatishPatro don't use null collections or streams. Use empty collections and streams. Then you don't have to worry about nulls.

Comment: what if we call distinct() on null stream list

Answer (score 7):

Calling `stream()` on a non-null object should never return `null`. So checking the *stream* to be `null` seems not to be necessary.

If the stream is empty, nothing will happen. So why check?

And yes, there are methodes in the JDK that help you check for an argument not being  `null`. Take a look at [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html).

Comment: okay. I thought it is overhead to iterate at least throw. That point got cleared. Second part? Checking null in java 8 funtion? Will it work. Instead of cars.stream().map() using Optional.ofNullable(cars).map()

Comment: It will make no difference in practice. You will prefer the simpler `cars.stream().map()`.

Comment: well if the collection is null and applying sream() in that will return NullPointerException. Isn't it?